# Reveal animation does not work on view with alignParentRight parameter

Tags: android, animation

I'm using [Google tutorial](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/material/animations.html) to create reveal animation for layout.
All works fine until I added alignParentRight="true" attribute to ripple layout. It just appears to VISIBLE whithout any animation.

here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ripple"
        android:alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="@color/black_transparent_60"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and here code to show this layout with reveal animation:

int cx = (myView.getLeft() + myView.getRight()) / 2;
    int cy = (myView.getTop() + myView.getBottom()) / 2;

```
int finalRadius = Math.max(myView.getWidth(), myView.getHeight());

Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);

anim.setDuration(1000);

myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mButtonShow.setVisibility(View.GONE);

anim.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cx was calculated wrong.

this code works fine:

```
 final int cx = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

        final int finalRadius = Math.max(myView.getWidth(), myView.getHeight());

        Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, 0, 0, finalRadius);
```

Comment: are you able to have reveal effect for your view? If yes then can you please update whole code for the effect here? because i am also having same issue and still i am not able to have reveal effect for my view.

Comment: iDroid Explorer, here is full code: final int cx = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            final int finalRadius = Math.max(myView.getWidth(), myView.getHeight());

            Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, 0, 0, finalRadius);

            anim.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);

            myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mButtonShow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            anim.start();